# Not solved import controllers.Application in Scala´s Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I´m developing a Play Framework project in Scala, but I not able to get correctly the `import controllers.Application` reference.

The snippet bellow focus on the `onStart` method at my `Global.scala` file, that is located inside the `app` directory. What is going under the hood? Why can´t I get this easy import done correctly?

```
import play.api._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random
import model.StatusUpdate

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    import controllers.{Application => App}
    // Definition of the onStart method.
}
```

My `Application.scala` file that is located in the controllers directory is defined as bellow:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {
   //Definition of methods
}
```

Comment: `Application` comes from the `play.api` package, why are you trying to import it from `controllers`?

Comment: @Ryan, because I wanna have access to some `controllers.Application` attributes, initialize them globally, and then, to establish a certain context before invoke the proper `http` requests.

Comment: @Ryan I think `controllers.Application` is one if his controllers. The main play app template has one named that way.

Comment: @m-z, exactly. It is one of my controllers that I had defined.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? And you can just invoke everything using `controllers.Application.whateverYouWanted`.

Comment: Without seeing the actual error you're hitting it's hard to tell, but it may be due to ambiguity between your `App` import and the  `scala.App` type.